# How can I make the city guards fight each other?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-iv-oblivion

I just completed the quest *Aid for Bruma*. I am trying to think of a way to make the guards in Bruma fight each other.

Apparently the guards from each city will unite against the player when I slash them or cast frenzy on them.

Answer (score 6):

The Frenzy spell effect is the only way to make guards fight each other, but the catch is, if anyone sees you do it, it counts as assault (which is why the guards are turning hostile to you, and demanding you pay fines).

The issue with guards in particular is that they are always 10 levels higher than the player, which means actually affecting them with the frenzy spell can be hard. A Level 25 frenzy spell will *always* work, but only if the player is at 100% spell effectiveness (i.e., isn't wearing any armor).